# c++ SDL_mixer error, Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src

Tags: c++, audio, visual-studio-2019, sdl-mixer

For some reason not all sounds is working. The Mix_GetError() returns this error message `Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src`

I have 57 different sound files loaded and 8 of them is not working and they all give the same error.[image]

The 8 sounds that does not work is the 8 in the very bottom of the picture. It is weird that the 8 that does not work is in the bottom and not spread out. *Is there a limit to how many or how many KB of sounds you can load in?*

Comment: I could be wrong, but I guess you just forgot to add ".wav" file extension at the end

Comment: Thank you so much. Dont understand how i could miss that, i spent 3h trying to fix it but failed.

Comment: This sometimes happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to add ".wav" file extension at the end.